# Thymeleaf can't resolve templates in multimodule SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf, multi-module

I have got problem described in title.

I created multimodule SpringBoot project with following structure:

- parent-module (pom packaging)

  - front-module (jar packaging)
  - business-module (jar packaging)
  - run-module (war packaging)

When I run application directly via IntelliJ it works fine, but when I build package via Maven and run in console created run-module.war file it throws:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [pages/example-page], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar!/:9.0.29]
...
```

I can see that inside run-module.war there is a front-module.jar as lib.

Anybody knows how to "tell" Thymeleaf where templates are?

Comment: Please show any configuration you have.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-  I don't have any configuration. I tried just with adding following properties:


`spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/lib/front-module.jar/templates`
`spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by following configuration, it is important to create a ClassLoaderTemplateResolver:

```java
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the protocol "classpath" to your prefix without an jar file name

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

Comment: Thank You for answer but, unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for more potential issues:

Problem for us, was that an improper class loader was used to retrieve the resources, one that didn't see any resources it seems. This was a side-effect of using an asynchronous CompletableFuture.

Our workaround was to reuse the classloader from the thread that created the CompletableFuture object.

```
var classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
    someAction();
});
```